# How to display an Alert view after number of taps received

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

As the title suggestes im trying to work out how I can show an alert after a button recives a certain amount of taps.  So far ive come up with

```
- (IBAction)count:(id)sender {

{
    UITouch *touch = [count];
    if (touch.tapCount == 4)
    {
}
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"My alert text here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

[alert show];

 }

}
```

The above isnt working, Ive set up my button `count`as action and as an  outlet `counted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't make a lot of sense (I'm surprised it compiles, does it?). UITouch isn't part of when you select a button. I think what you need to do is to keep a count of how many times the button is pressed, and store it as an instance variable.

For example (in your implementation):

```
@interface ClassName() {
    NSUInteger m_buttonTouchCount;
}
@end

// Set m_buttonTouchCount to 0 in your init/appear method, whenever it's appropriate to reset it

- (IBAction)count:(id)sender {
{
    m_touchButtonCount++
    if (m_touchButtonCount == 4)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                                        message:@"My alert text here" 
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        m_touchButtonCount = 0; // Not sure if you want to reset to 0 here.
    }
 }
```

Comment: No doesn't compile just showing that id at least made an effort to solve it myself.  Thank you for your help that works great! Just had to change NSUinteger `m_buttonTouchCount` to `m_touchButtonCount` for anyone else who may need this code.

Answer (score 0):

Define somewhere on the begining of code static value:

```
static int numberTouches;
```

And set somewhere (in viewWillAppear):

numberTouches = 0;

Than:

```
- (IBAction)count:(id)sender {
{
    numberTouches++;
    if(numberTouches == 4)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"My alert text here" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Remeber to set 0 to your numberTouches in place where you want to do this, for example in viewDidDissapear, or if user taped somewhere else.

Comment: I'd personally refrain from using `static int numberTouches;`, it's more of a relic from C, and to the novice the use of static in this context is confusing (could mean it's global across all instances of the class, when in reality it just means the variable has file scope). The Obj-C method is more through the use of properties and class extensions.